# Local/Synth Storage is not being set

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There is never an entry in the local/sync Storage, even though the alert is being displayed.

script.js:

```
    document.getElementById('save').onclick = function() {
      chrome.storage.local.set({"ad": "1"}, function() {
      console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
    });
    alert('Boop');
};`
```

manifest:

```
"options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html",
        "chrome_style": true
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ],
```

html:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="padding:30px">
    <p>Enter your name: <input id="name"></p>
    <input id="save" type="button" value="SAVE">
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's not shown in devtools, see [Inspect chrome.storage.sync while debugging Chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/32471596)

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the problem, that I am getting "undefined" in my outputstring, even though the console shows the correct value. It might be async, but I don't see an option to change this.

Comment: It is also strange, that I need to open and submit the options for every tab again, before it actually displays the correct value. So: Not opening the option --> undefined. Opening the option and clicking 'save' again --> correct value

Comment: Sounds like that other code (that runs in a tab) is incorrect.